# Masking zeroes in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, embedding, masking

My data set is satellite observation which includes a lot of zeroes so that highly effect my final simulation results.

I have two sets of input data, dynamic ones (X_dynamic_LSTM.shape (95931, 1, 5)) which change through time series and static ones (X_static_MLP.shape (95931, 10)) which is not change. For dynamic ones I used LSTM and for static ones the MLP. I Concatenate the two and get the final results by another MLP.

Can you suggest how should I ignore these zero variables in my prediction dataframe??? I know about **Masking** and **Embedding** but don't know how to add them in my code!

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Masking
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding

lstm_input = Input(shape=(X_dynamic_LSTM.shape[1], X_dynamic_LSTM.shape[2]))

x = Masking(mask_value=0.)(lstm_input)
x = LSTM(70, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = LSTM(35)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = Dense(1, activation='tanh')(x)

#mlp input with additonal 3 variables at t=t
mlp_input=Input(shape=(X_static_MLP.shape[1]))
mlp = Dense(30, activation='relu')(mlp_input)
mlp = Dense(20, activation='relu')(mlp)

merge = Concatenate()([x, mlp])
hidden1 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(merge)
mlp_out = Dense(1, activation='relu')(hidden1)


model = Model(inputs=[lstm_input, mlp_input],outputs=mlp_out)

#compile the model
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

#fit the model
model.fit([X_dynamic_LSTM, X_static_MLP], y_train, batch_size=40,
          epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use embedding layer in your first layer

you can use this [link](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/)

```
>>> model = tf.keras.Sequential()
>>> model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding())
```

Comment: I know about this, but how should I define Embedding parameters? most documents are about text prediction... how should I define "input_dim" or "output_dim" ??